# using ngOptions & ngModel with multiple objects & scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using ngOptions on a select field to generate a list of options.

What I'd like to do is have the dropdown be populated with a full list of departments, but have the default option be selected according to the department a user is assigned to.

For each user, they can only be assigned to one department, but each dropdown contains the same list of departments.

So I need to join users.departments.key to users.list.departmentId somehow, while keeping everything in ngModel scoped properly.

I can change where I store the departments (anywhere in $scope) but changing $scope.users will cause problems elsewhere in the application.

```js
$scope.users.departments = [
  {
    key: 123, 
    value: 'Advertising'
  },
  {
    key: 114,
    value: 'Editorial'
  },
  {etc}]

$scope.users.list = [
    {
      firstName: 'john',
      lastname: 'smith',
      departmentId: 123
    },
    {etc},
    {etc}]
```

Plunkr link here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7CuIxwUX3Qrb8qxUm3n0?p=preview

Using the above select statement in ngOptions, I can get all the departments to appear in the dropdown, but I don't know how to have the option for each user showing. Also, I'd like to be able to fire a callback function on change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gCICcfRCwI0ochamvqlK?p=preview) so it works as you expected.

Basically you just need to change the way you are rendering the options, setting the model to be the departmentId of the user and making departments keys to be the value of the selected option.

```
<select name="departmentSelect" 
        ng-model="u.departmentId" 
        ng-options="department.key as department.value for department in users.departments">
</select>
```

Cheers, Pablo.